# Scala Spark-> Select first 15 columns from a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

**I am trying to get the first 15 columns from a DataFrame that contains more than 500 cols. But I don't know how to do it because is my first time using Scala Spark.**

I was searching but didn't find anything, just how to get cols by name, for example:

```
val df2 = df.select("firstColName", "secondColeName")
```

How can i do this by index?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala example:

```
df.selectExpr(df.columns.take(15):_*)
```

Comment: That was I was looking for! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: df.columns has type of Array[String], then you need to map it to Array[Column]: df.select(df.columns.take(15).map(col) :_*)